# Subsampling an array of numbers

Tags: c++, downsampling

I have a series of 100 integer values which I need to reduce/subsample to 77 values for the purpose of fitting into a predefined space on screen. This gives a fraction of 77/100 values-per-pixel - not very neat.

Assuming the 77 is fixed and cannot be changed, what are some typical techniques for subsampling 100 numbers down to 77. I get a sense that it will be a jagged mapping, by which I mean the first new value is the average of [0, 1] then the next value is [3], then average [4, 5] etc. But how do I approach getting the pattern for this mapping?

I am working in C++, although I'm more interested in the technique than implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use standard interpolation techniques?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways of interpolation (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation))

The linear one would be something like:

```
std::array<int, 77> sampling(const std::array<int, 100>& a)
{
     std::array<int, 77> res;

     for (int i = 0; i != 76; ++i) {
         int index = i * 99 / 76;
         int p = i * 99 % 76;

         res[i] = ((p * a[index + 1]) + ((76 - p) * a[index])) / 76;
    }
    res[76] = a[99]; // done outside of loop to avoid out of bound access (0 * a[100])
    return res;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/w40sIg)

Answer (score 4):

Either if you downsample or you oversample, you are trying to reconstruct a signal over nonsampled points in time... so you have to make some assumptions.

The sampling theorem tells you that if you sample a signal knowing that it has no frequency components over half the sampling frequency, you can continously and completely recover the signal over the whole timing period.  There's a way to reconstruct the signal using `sinc()` functions (this is `sin(x)/x`)

`sinc()` (indeed `sin(M_PI/Sampling_period*x)/M_PI/x`) is a function that has the following properties:

1. Its value is 1 for `x == 0.0` and 0 for `x == k*Sampling_period` with `k == 0, +-1, +-2, ...`
2. It has no frequency component over half of the sampling_frequency derived from `Sampling_period`.

So if you consider the sum of the functions `F_x(x) = Y[k]*sinc(x/Sampling_period - k)` to be the sinc function that equals the sampling value at position `k` and 0 at other sampling value and sum over all k in your sample, you'll get the best continous function that has the properties of not having components on frequencies over half the sampling frequency and have the same values as your samples set.

Said this, you can resample this function at whatever position you like, getting the best way to resample your data.

This is by far, a complicated way of resampling data, (it has also the problem of not being causal, so it cannot be implemented in real time) and you have several methods used in the past to simplify the interpolation.  you have to constructo all the sinc functions for each sample point and add them together.  Then you have to resample the resultant function to the new sampling points and give that as a result.

Next is an example of the interpolation method just described. It accepts some input data (`in_sz` samples) and output interpolated data with the method described before (I supposed the extremums coincide, which makes `N+1` samples equal `N+1` samples, and this makes the somewhat intrincate calculations of `(in_sz - 1)/(out_sz - 1)` in the code (change to `in_sz/out_sz` if you want to make plain `N samples -> M samples` conversion:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* normalized sinc function */
double sinc(double x)
{
    x *= M_PI;
    if (x == 0.0) return 1.0;
    return sin(x)/x;
} /* sinc */

/* interpolate a function made of in samples at point x */
double sinc_approx(double in[], size_t in_sz, double x)
{
    int i;
    double res = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < in_sz; i++)
            res += in[i] * sinc(x - i);
    return res;
} /* sinc_approx */

/* do the actual resampling.  Change (in_sz - 1)/(out_sz - 1) if you
 * don't want the initial and final samples coincide, as is done here.
 */
void resample_sinc(
    double in[],
    size_t in_sz,
    double out[],
    size_t out_sz)
{
    int i;
    double dx = (double) (in_sz-1) / (out_sz-1);
    for (i = 0; i < out_sz; i++)
            out[i] = sinc_approx(in, in_sz, i*dx);
}

/* test case */
int main()
{
    double in[] = {
            0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0,
    };

    const size_t in_sz = sizeof in / sizeof in[0];
    const size_t out_sz = 5;
    double out[out_sz];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < in_sz; i++)
            printf("in[%d] = %.6f\n", i, in[i]);
    resample_sinc(in, in_sz, out, out_sz);
    for (i = 0; i < out_sz; i++)
            printf("out[%.6f] = %.6f\n", (double) i * (in_sz-1)/(out_sz-1), out[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* main */
```

Comment: Really thank you for the detailed explanation, very useful

Answer (score 1):

Create 77 new pixels based on the weighted average of their positions.

As a toy example, think about the 3 pixel case which you want to subsample to 2.

Original (denote as multidimensional array `original` with RGB as [0, 1, 2]):

```
|----|----|----|
```

Subsample (denote as multidimensional array `subsample` with RGB as [0, 1, 2]):

```
|------|------|
```

Here, it is intuitive to see that the first subsample seems like 2/3 of the first original pixel and 1/3 of the next.

For the first subsample pixel, `subsample[0]`, you make it the RGB average of the `m` original pixels that overlap, in this case `original[0] and original[1]`. But we do so in weighted fashion.

```
subsample[0][0] = original[0][0] * 2/3 + original[1][0] * 1/3  # for red
subsample[0][1] = original[0][1] * 2/3 + original[1][1] * 1/3  # for green
subsample[0][2] = original[0][2] * 2/3 + original[1][2] * 1/3  # for blue
```

In this example `original[1][2]` is the green component of the second original pixel.

Keep in mind for different subsampling you'll have to determine the set of original cells that contribute to the subsample, and then normalize to find the relative weights of each.

There are much more complex graphics techniques, but this one is simple and works.

Comment: Thanks lollercoaster, very clear explanation. Fortunatly for me my problem is only 1D values so I can skip over the RGB elements.

3->2 seems very intuitive, but 100 -> 77 does not. How can I work to make this mental leap?

Comment: With a pen and paper? Trying more cases and developing an intuition about how the numbers work? It's not a programming question, it's just a sitting down and thinking about it question.

Comment: You are going to need a function that translates `n` original numbers to `m` new slots by assigning each `m`th sample a normalized weighting of each of the `n` original numbers. in practice, it won't be very many original bins that contribute, but you'll need a function that steps through and assigns the subsample array one by one. as you take steps of 1.0/100, when you cross each multiple of 1.0/77, you'll need to assign the last subsample cell to the last set of original cells in weighted fashion. If this approach answers your question, please mark it as such!

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what you wish to do with the data - how do you want to visualize it.

A very simple approach would be to render to a 100-wide image, and then smooth scale the image down to a narrower size. Whatever graphics/development framework you're using will surely support such an operation.

Say, though, that your goal might be to retain certain qualities of the data, such as minima and maxima. In such a case, for each bin, you're drawing a line of darker color up to the minimum value, and then continue with a lighter color up to the maximum. Or, you could, instead of just putting a pixel at the average value, you draw a line from the minimum to the maximum.

Finally, you might wish to render as if you had 77 values only - then the goal is to somehow transform the 100 values down to 77. This will imply some kind of an interpolation. Linear or quadratic interpolation is easy, but adds distortions to the signal. Ideally, you'd probably want to throw a sinc interpolator at the problem. A good list of them can be found [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/Free_Resampling_Software.html). For theoretical background, look [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/).